# How to build a multiplatform Eclipse update site with Tycho

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde

On my PDE/Tycho Eclipse environment I want to build a plugin of type eclipse-repository which contains 3 features each one for a specific platform.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The eclipse-repository plugin reads all its configuration from a parent plugin which content is the following:

```xml
<properties>
  <tycho.version>0.26.0</tycho.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>neon</id>
   <layout>p2</layout>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>

    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>

    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>

    <configuration>
        <environments>
          <environment>
            <os>win32</os>
            <ws>win32</ws>
            <arch>x86</arch>
          </environment>
          <environment>
            <os>linux</os>
            <ws>gtk</ws>
            <arch>x86_64</arch>
          </environment>
          <environment>
            <os>macosx</os>
            <ws>cocoa</ws>
            <arch>x86_64</arch>
          </environment>
        </environments>
    </configuration>

   </plugin>   
  </plugins>
 </build>
```

When I try to build the eclpse-repository project I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:0.26.0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) on project ... : Execution default-assemble-repository of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:0.26.0:assemble-repository failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject ...
```

Comment: Looks like I fell into this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407273